# adding swap to grub and speed up ubuntu boot page

Tags: swap, boot-time

i installed ubuntu 16.04
its splash screen boot page takes long time to go to entering password page.
also, system can not recognize swap and in system monitor, swap is inactive. my swap partition is primary.
can anyone help?
thanks

Comment: What makes you believe that swap isn't working correctly? What do you mean by your swap partition is primary? Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk` and `swapon` and `free -h`. Please copy/paste... don't take a picture.

Comment: /dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="A4AEC7AFAEC777F6" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="84787d7c-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="swap" UUID="e7ec9aca-902f-4ae9-82be-0ebde434513b" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="84787d7c-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="9f4fb20a-e908-416e-bded-a65e4fdad607" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="84787d7c-03"
/dev/sda5: UUID="9f658f2c-dd17-4713-acc1-45e137854d7c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="84787d7c-05"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Data" UUID="79A384C3750D49DB" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="84787d7c-06"

Comment: # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=9f4fb20a-e908-416e-bded-a65e4fdad607 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation

Comment: NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     8G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   542G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   100G  0 part 
└─sda6   8:6    0   281G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

Comment: total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5.7G        1.1G        430M        3.2G        4.2G        1.1G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

Comment: these are the outputs of commands.

Comment: when system starts, in system monitor swap is not available.

Comment: Thanks for responding with the command outputs. Unfortunately it's extremely difficult to read them when they're placed into comments. Can I ask that you do the commands again, and edit (copy/paste with formatting) them into your original question? Also show me `sudo fdisk -l`. If your fstab was complete, it's missing a lot of stuff. How do you use sda5 and sda6 (Data)? You can delete the comments with that data.

Comment: Even though my answer is incomplete, you can go ahead and do what I have there now. That'll fix your swap.

Answer (score 0):

## Step #1

- edit `/etc/fstab` in `terminal`, type...

  - `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`
  - to include this...

```
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=e7ec9aca-902f-4ae9-82be-0ebde434513b  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

- save an quit gedit
- still in `terminal`, type...

  - `swapon -a`
  - `reboot`

## Step #2

- after reboot, in `terminal`, type...

  - `swapon`
  - `free -h`